# Permutation Algorithm: Why arr[i] + perm(all_but_not_i) is the same with perm(all_but_not_i)+arr[i]?

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

Considering the typical permutation algorithm below

```py
def permutation(arr):   
    if len(arr) == 0: 
        return [[]] 
    if len(arr) == 1: 
        return [arr]
    result = [] 
    for i in range(len(arr)): 
        val = arr[i] 
        remain = arr[:i] + arr[i+1:]
        for p in permutation(remain): 
            result.append([val]+p) 
    return result
```

In the line 11, why it does it not matter if it is `[val]+p` or `p+[val]`? The order of the result isn't important.

Comment: Why would it matter? Addition is commutative in most cases, why do you expect that it's not here?

Comment: @AdamSmith I want to understand the algorithm well, more specific, I'm looking for proof that `[val] + permutation(remain)` is the same `permutation(remain)+[val]` in the perspective of a bag of permutations.